# How to make a rest call using oauth2.0

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication

My resource server uses Oauth2 for authentication. We use google to authenticate the user. So basically Google is used as authentication server. 'tegile' is used as domain when authenticating.

What is the way to get bearer token from Google that I can pass to my resource server as part of REST header?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use [Google's Sign-In button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) template to initialize the login & grant of permissions process:

```html
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{{ OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID }}">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>

<div id="google-signin-button"
     class="g-signin2"
     data-width="170"
     data-height="30"
     data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
     data-onfailure="onSignInFailure">
</div>
```

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var idToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
}
```